# jQuery Filter: Having trouble displaying a message when nothing is found

Tags: jquery

so I've been trying to show a message when no search result if found, I've tried other threads, but it didn't quite work, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Here's my code so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();    
    $("#myDIV *").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#txt{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Filter Anything</h2>
<p>Type something in the input field to search for a specific text inside the div element with id="myDIV":</p>

<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<div id="myDIV">
  <p>I am a paragraph.</p>
  <div>I am a div element inside div.</div>
  <button>I am a button</button>
  <button>Another button</button>
  <p>Another paragraph.</p>
  <p id="txt">Nothing found</p>
</div>
```

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/goprime/pen/NOKNmZ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class to the elements which are searchable and check if any of them is `:visisble` to determine whether `#txt` should be shown or hidden.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    $("#myDIV .item").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });

    $(".item:visible").length == 0 ? $('#txt').show() : $('#txt').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#txt {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Filter Anything</h2>
<p>Type something in the input field to search for a specific text inside the div element with id="myDIV":</p>
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<div id="myDIV">
  <p class="item">I am a paragraph.</p>
  <div class="item">I am a div element inside div.</div>
  <button class="item">I am a button</button>
  <button class="item">Another button</button>
  <p class="item">Another paragraph.</p>
  <p id="txt">Nothing found</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much, it works perfectly, have a great day!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.